# How to use a template to create two very similar member functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am coding a C++ library and one class has two member functions that only differ in one function call:

```cpp
int MyClass::member_func_1(int a) {
   // ...
   int b = some_function();
   // ...
}

int MyClass::member_func_2(int a) {
   // ...
   int b = some_other_function();
   // ...
}
```

Is there a way of not having to duplicate the code of these two functions, while still keeping the two member functions with the same function signatures?

- Since it is a library all code must be generated when the library is compiled.
- I have ruled out the option of having only one member function with an extra boolean argument to choose between `some_function` and `some_other_function` for performance reasons.
- I know how to use a macro to do it, but could a template be used, or is there another better way?

Comment: Can you explain what prevents the obvious solution of replacing the first "// ..." in these two functions with a call to private class method called "ellipsis_1()", and the second "// ..." in these two functions with a call to another private class method called "ellipsis_2()". This is just one  of many ways to factor out the common code, in C++.

Comment: I assume that the call to `some_function` or `some_other_function`, in addition to some code in ellipsis, is executed in a tight loop. Otherwise the performance problem is a mirage and other solution than my proposed answer would better fit.

Comment: The setting is high performance scientific computing, so speed of execution is more important than maintainability of the code. My current solution is to simply duplicate the code, but I thought we could do a bit better on maintainability than that.

Comment: The calls to some_function and some_other_function are actually in a loop inside the member functions so I suspect (noticeable) performance loss with an if, but I would of course need to measure to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `template` solution is only a good solution if the call to either of the member functions is executed in a tight loop, where the overhead of testing a boolean or making an indirect function call would be too costly.

In this case, if C++17 standard is an option, the `if constexpr` syntax is probably the simplest way. Like in:

```
class MyClass
{
    template<bool other> int member_func(int a)
    {
        //...
        int b;
        if constexpr (other)
            b = some_other_function();
        else
            b = some_function();
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: I like this solution. Unfortunately I can only use C++11, but apart from constexpr, I think that this could still be used. How would the two methods be instantiated from the template?

Comment: Well, without `if constexpr` (my favorite feature by far from C++17), writing a template function for the same feature is doable, but it is a _pain_. You will need to specialize at least one template class. If `MyClass` has several other members than that `template` one, I think you would need a `template` helper functor class just for that.

Comment: no need to specialize the whole class. Only picking either `some_function` or `some_other_function` has to be in the template. The `member_func`  would then call `some_template_fun<other>` that is specialized to call either of the two (perhaps pass pointer to this)

Comment: How could this template be used to create the two member functions that could be called without any template syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Since the only difference in the implementation of your two member functions is the calls to different member functions, that's what you should abstract out of those functions. You can do that by writing a single member function that takes a pointer to member function as an additional argument:

```
int common_member_func(int a, int (MyClass::*func)())
{
  // ...
  int b = (this->*func)();
  // ...
}
```

and now the implementation of your two member functions would be:

```
int member_func_1(int a) 
{
  return common_member_func(a, &MyClass::some_function);
}

int member_func_2(int a)
{
  return common_member_func(a, &MyClass::some_other_function);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xe6ehq).

Answer (score 1):

You may use a boolean for switching the internal method to be called or pass a function pointer / std::function and call that one directly. the performance penalty will be ridiculously negligible.

If you really want to make your code less readable because of that virtually non-existant "performance reason", you can implement the common method templated, with a boolean template parameter. The if() clause referring the template parameter can then be a constexpr (realised during compilation).

However note that this will also lead to the method being effectively doubled in your applications code, and when you have many alternating calls, this might have an adverse effect on your performance similar to the original if() clause, i.e. not noticable at all.

Comment: _"the performance penalty will be ridiculously negligible"_ likely, but unsubstantiated.